# Office Interop Track changes - show markup

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

How do I set the track changes view to `Final: Show Markup` when using interop  to manipulate Word documents?

I know that I can [turn track changes on/off](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.trackrevisions). I also found a property called `View.MarkupMode` but this only deals with what is actually shown in the markup (comment bubbles and stuff) rather than setting the view to `Final: Show Markup`.

There is also some mention of using `WdRevisionsView` but this doesn't have an option to show markup, only the original or final.

[image: Image showing the different views used with track changes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple properties of `Word.View` that get are at once when switching to the "Final: Show Markup" view. This should do it:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Word.View v = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View;

v.RevisionsView = Word.WdRevisionsView.wdRevisionsViewFinal;
v.ShowRevisionsAndComments = true;
v.ShowComments = true;
v.ShowFormatChanges = true;
v.ShowInkAnnotations = true;
v.ShowInsertionsAndDeletions = true;
```